# In Appium 1.0+, now that finding elements by tag is deprecated, how do I find an element by tag name when operating on the DOM of the webview?

Tags: appium

Once I switch my context to the DOM of the webview, I want to be able to search those elements by tag, but I get the error that searching by tag is deprecated and to search by class instead. This won't work to find DOM elements by tag.  Is there still a way to do it?  Thanks!

Comment: Please change the title to something shorter like: "How to find element by tag (deprecated) in Appium 1.0+?" Too long titles are very difficult to handle and they would likely make harder for you to receive answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per Appium [documentation for migrating to 1.0](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-1-0.md):

> We've removed the following locator strategies:
>
> ```
> -name
> -tag name
> ```
>
> ... tag name has been replaced by class name. So to find an element by its
>   UI type, use the class name locator strategy for your client.

### Why searching by tag name?

Although Selenium still supports this type of query, Appium decided not to do anymore. Actually when interacting with the device, searching by tag name is very inefficient.

Why would you want to do that? Think about it, if your page has a bit of content, you will end up having many `p`, `div`, `span` tags. Your search will return many elements and then you will have to go thorugh the list and locate the one you are interested in. If your page is very little, then you will probably end up with one tag of the type you are looking for, however why not applying a class and solve the problem?

### Classes are not for CSS style

Remember that HTML attribute `class` was not introduced by W3C for applying CSS style. It is used to provide an element with more informationa bout its purpose in the DOM. When you apply a class to an element, you should do that basing on the role that element holds! Thus locating an element by class is sure better.

So forget searching by tag name. You should change your strategy and apply class names to your tags in your hybrid app. If you do not want to do so, then do not switch to the new version of Appium but this will keep you far from future innovations!

> Migrating from a tagname based element location to a class name
>   orientd one is good practice. That's why you should change too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
element.getAttribute("class")
```